# apachesorl returns 400 bad request on search with % symbol

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, solr, bad-request

I stuck at strange thing - apachesolr returns Bad Request when i'm trying to search with % symbol.
I guess it's some kind of settings trouble, because on test server with same solr-1.4.1 I don't have any problems with %.

I'm using apachesolr module for drupal 6 (version 1.5), solr 1.4.1, and SolrPhpClient -r22. I've checked that modules and drupal settings the same.
Does anybody knows what might cause such problem?

Comment: Here what I found: seems that apache (not apachesolr) double decoded special chars, so for %, it needs to be %2525, not just %25 (encoded %). I fixed this by patching apachesolr module

Comment: :
file apachesolr.module:906-912
`function see apachesolr_search_search_box_form_submit()
  // Handle Apache webserver clean URL quirks.
  if (variable_get('clean_url', '0')) {
    $keys = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keys);
    $keys = str_replace('%', '%25', $keys); //fix to problem;
  }`
and
file apachesolr_search.module:1803-1807
function apachesolr_l()
// Double encode + characters for clean URL Apache quirks.
  if (variable_get('clean_url', '0')) {
    $path = str_replace('+', '%2B', $path);
    $path = str_replace('%', '%25', $path); //fix to problem;
  }

Comment: However, I still don't know what the exact reason of this problem happening on my prod env and not happening on my test env.

Comment: Is there a proxy in front of ApacheSOLR? It seems that between Drupal and ApacheSOLR your strings get encoded, which they should not.